# Front-end web projects developed in separate repos from back-end project (API)

Tags: node.js, git, backend, web-frontend

Say you are developing a web front-end called F and F is served by a backend server S, which is mostly a RESTful API, but can also serve HTML. For most dynamic language platforms, we would put that front-end code in the public directory, and the server would serve pages from that directory. However, what if you develop the front-end in a separate repo from the back-end code?

In other words, what is the best way to keep the source code for F in a separate git repo from server S? How do developers keep the web front-end for servers in separate projects for the back-end. Or perhaps this is not common for web servers?

My guess is that for outfits that choose to develop the front-end in a separate project, then they do this as a build-step - they copy the source code for the web front-end to a recognized directory for the backend server project S.

Hope this question makes sense.

From what I can tell, Polymer's Vulcanize what I am trying to refer to - it provides a build step which generates an HTML file in the right location - https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like a very common use case for git [`submodules`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [`subtrees`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)

Alternatively, if your frontend people *never* develop `S`, and your backend people *never* develop `F`, then you should be using package dependency managers like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). `F` devs include `S` as a dependency, and `S` devs include `F` as a dependency.